# how to find minimum value from result set using cursor in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, cursor, sql-order-by

I am using cursor on below temporary reultset

```
SELECT price FROM flight where source1='delhi' and dest='Bangkok';
```

I want to find minimum ticket price of flight on above route.
How to do this?

Comment: I don't want to use aggregate function min()

Comment: how to compare 1st row value with 2nd and print min value in cursor?

Comment: Use a price comparison website. Seriously, why a cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, **ORDER BY** AND **LIMIT**

```
SELECT `price` FROM flight 
WHERE `source1` = 'delhi' 
AND `dest` = 'Bangkok' 
ORDER BY `price` ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Where one answer is a duplicate of another, etiquette would seem to favour upvoting and acceptance of the first.

Comment: @Strawberry His actual requirement was to get the minimum,and query without LIMIT wouldn't help. That's why I posted a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use **ORDER BY** clause to order your desired result.

Try this:

```
SELECT price 
FROM flight 
WHERE source1='delhi' AND dest='Bangkok' 
ORDER BY price ASC;
```

**OR**

If you want only minimum price then Use **LIMIT** also.

```
SELECT price 
FROM flight 
WHERE source1='delhi' AND dest='Bangkok' 
ORDER BY price ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Order by` because it filter your result in ascending or descending sequence.

```
SELECT price FROM flight where source1='delhi' and dest='Bangkok' order by price asc
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all record of that's route by min to max order then use **ORDER BY price DESC** after your query

```
SELECT price FROM flight where source1='delhi' and dest='Bangkok' 
ORDER BY price DESC;
```

**OR**

If you want to get only one minimum price then you can use **MIN()** function.

```
SELECT MIN(price) FROM flight where source1='delhi' and dest='Bangkok';
```